# Is it possible to pass Keys.TAB or Keys.Slash using Jmeter through groovy script?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to pass Keys.TAB or Keys.Slash using Jmeter HTTP request through a groovy script?

Comment: pass Keys.TAB where?what are you going to load with jmeter?

Comment: I am passing the parameter to the HTTP request which is a mathematical equation/formula, through groovy/ BeanShell scripting I can read the variable and pass it to the request e.g. this is I can see in the request, \\frac{dRT}{P} and \\mathit{X}{_A}=\\frac{nA}{nA+nB+nC}. the request gets failed if I keep it as is. So I would like to know how to handle these frac and math equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if pressing tab or slash triggers a network request to your server - you can mimic it by sending the corresponding [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) via [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). You can check whether pressing a key generates network activity by looking at "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

If pressing a key doesn't generate a HTTP request - you won't be able to test this scenario using JMeter, you will need a real browser driven by the browser automation framework like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). JMeter can be integrated with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/)